# Count employees per their qualifications

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I have a set of trainings and qualifications, and my goal is to count how many employees are qualified based on the training that they took.

[image]

I have only 1 employee who is qualified for (qualification1), so I'm trying to find a way to calculate and count the employees who are qualified for a specific qualification based on specific trainings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 employees with Qualification1. 100 and 101, because both Training1 and Training2 have Qualification1 as Qualification Name and in the first table employee 100 and 101 have at least one line with Done status.